# Playwright Specflow tests are throwing exception in debug mode but not throwing any exception in run mode

Tags: ui-automation, playwright, specflow, playwright-dotnet

I am running tests in VS-2022 using Specflow and playwright. Below is the scenario happening with me.
Debug Mode: While running test in Debug mode few steps are running fine but at one step its directly closing the browser and throwing the exception **"An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.Playwright.TargetClosedException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Target page, context or browser has been closed"**

Run Mode: If I am trying to run the same test in normal mode its showing all green but after few steps its showing 0.0s in standard output. Below are the steps.

```
And I click on "Activation" tab
-> done: ActivationSteps.WhenIClickOnTab("Activation") (1.2s)
When I delete the activation
-> done: Activation.WhenIDeleteActivation() (0.0s)
Then 0 activations are visible in "Activation"
-> done: AcRulesSteps.ThenRulesAreVisibleIn(0, "Activation") (0.0s)
```

Can someone help me why this is happening?

I tried changing the xpath's.

Comment: Can you share the code on the test step that is failing please

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [repro]. We do not have enough information to provide answer.